# Could not load inherited class for aspx page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When I transfer my project to a server, I now get this error message. What does it mean and how do I fix it?

```
 Server Error in '/HD' Application.

    Parser Error

    Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

    Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'HD._Default'.

    Source Error: 


    Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="HD._Default" %>
    Line 2:  
    Line 3:  <%@ Register Assembly="FormControls" Namespace="FormControls" TagPrefix="FC" %>

    Source File: /helpdeskform/HD/default.aspx    Line: 1
```

Comment: How did you transfer the project to the server?

Answer (score 1):

The `@Page` directive included this attribute: `Inherits="HD._Default"`.

This means that there is a class `_Default` in the `HD` namespace associated with this page.

The error means that this class cannot be found.

A fix depends on how the site is setup and deployed:

- You can solve this by copying the class to the correct location
- Use the Visual Studio deployment tool (right click the web project then Deploy)

I prefer using the deployment tool - you can deploy to a local folder to ensure all dependencies are there, then upload to a server if you are not comfortable or able to use the direct to server options.

Comment: I don't have a file that contains the name _default and have enabled hidden folders as visible. Also, I've right clicked my project and there is no 'deploy' option. I do however have a 'build deployment package' option

Comment: @jsmith - What version of VS are you using? Did you try the build deployment package?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010. I selected the build deployment package and did not get any errors

Comment: @jsmith - Well, what did you do with the deployment package that resulted?

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with it. There's a command line file that opens and closes without doing anything and the zip file itself has added about 5 extra levels of directory with xml at the outermost and innermost levels.